# Links in HTML - encode or clean?

Tags: html, urlencode

This is probably a very simple question. Consider a very simple situation:

```
<a href="some/url">some link</a>
```

Should the href parameter in HTML be url-encoded or simply with html-safe characters? Browsers normally just encode the link when navigating to it, but anyway ... is one of the two ways more correct than the other?

**UPDATE 1** some people managed to get confused and offer me to add "/" or "http://" to the url. People, this is completely irrelevant - i know very well how to form a url. The question is about url-encoding.

Comment: Without using "http://" it can concatenate the url on top of "index.html/" may be Im mistaken.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik you are correct, but this is just pseudocode-ish line, and it needs no fixing. The question is not about that - "some/url" might as well be written in "foo/bar" or "whatever" or "http:// whatever" - it's still just pseudocode(-ish).

Answer (score -1):

```
<a href="http://www.some/url"></a>
```

Will give you a link to an external page or website

```
<a href="www.some/url"></a>
```

Will give you an internal link to a page within your root folder ("index.html/www.some/url")

Comment: I am well aware of that, but it has absolutely nothing to do with the question. That was just pseudo-code in the example.